# Baked Normal Map Not Appearing on Mesh

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I've been continuing that Blender Anvil Modeling tutorial, and I've gotten stuck on the part in which I'm supposed to bake a normal.
I sculpted, and created a high-poly model, and then tried to bake the normals onto a low-poly model. (I hope I'm saying this correctly...)

The result was this fine normal map:
[image: a normal map]
I saved this image, added it as an image texture, plugged it into a Normal Map node, and plugged that into the "Normal" port of a Principled BSDF.

And nothing.
The low-poly mesh still looks the same. I've unwrappped the mesh. Image/Color textures work fine, but for some reason, the Normal Map does not work. The normals line up with the UV Map, the Image Texture is set to "Non-Color", and I don't know what else to try.

For reference, here's the node setup:
[image: A node setup]

---

And if anyone's willing to take a further look, various .blend files will be linked below:

Smaller anvil.blend file containing only the low-poly mesh + the normal map (1.6MB):
[image]
[Hyperlink for those with Script Blockers](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6328)

The original anvil.blend file containing the low-poly mesh, the high-poly mesh, and other stuff (137MB): [On Google Drive.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14d_Ot9FdikYeYgawM5QnhiW3vFetelKd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I opened your file, the image called *Normal* was not loaded in the *Image Texture* node, once done it seems to work fine:

[image]